# Conway's game of Life in C with malloc'd arrays

Tags: arrays, c

I'm implementing Conway's game of life with a malloc'd array as a grid of 0s and 1s, anywhere with a `0` I print a white background space representing a "dead" cell and anywhere with `1` I print a black background space representing an "alive" cell.

I'm having some trouble with updating the cells on each cycle. My approach was to have a `getState()` function, which just checks if a grid entry is `0` or `1` and then returns a value correspondingly. I also have a `countN()` function which goes through the grid, and counts the numbers - accounting for corner, edge and centre cases. I've tested those thoroughly with several examples and they are working how I expect them to, for a given grid coordinate it always returns the correct state & number of alive neighbours.

This is what I've attempted to do (pseudocode):

```
void updateGrid(int **grid, int r, int c) {
    copyGrid = grid;
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) 
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            alive->getState(grid, i, j) 
            neighbours->countN(grid, i, j)
          
            if (alive) {
                if (neighbour < 2 || neigbour > 3) 
                    copyGrid[i][j] = 0;
                else 
                    copyGrid[i][j] = 1;
            } else {
                if (neighbour == 3) 
                    copyGrid[i][j] = 1;
                else 
                    copyGrid[i][j] = 0; 
            }
        }
    grid = copyGrid; 
    printGrid(grid, r, c)
}
```

There's a simple calling function which just generates an initial grid from an input file, clears the screen and then calls `updateGrid()` and sleeps after each cycle, until a certain number of cycles. The initial grid is how I expect it to be, the neighbours and alive functions return the correct values but the grid updates incorrectly and the output is quite distorted.

As an example, using 1s and 0s:

```
Input:    Expected Output:     Actual Output
0 0 0     0 1 0                0 1 1 
1 1 1     0 1 0                1 0 1 
0 0 0     0 1 0                0 0 0
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That is sort of what I was tryna do, I had a separate copyGrid which I made equal to my original grid. I checked the neighbours & states of my original grid, but updated the contents of my copy grid. At the end I did grid = copyGrid and printed that out.

Comment: You are currently using only one bit out of the probably 32 (size of an `int`) you have available. It's much more efficient to use the 2nd bit for the "new" grid. So instead of creating a copy, you just "add" the 1 or 0 as the 2nd bit, while reading out only the 1st bit. Then when you have processed the entire grid, you can just bit-shift all grid fields one bit right, and you have the new state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method for copying the grid copy back to `grid` does not work: `copyGrid = grid;` and `grid = copyGrid;` don't not do that, the first overwrites the global pointer `copyGrid`, which causes the updated cells to be written to the original grid, the second does nothing as both pointers already point to the same area.

You must remove the `copyGrid = grid;` statement. All updated cells are computed and stored into `copyGrid` so there is no need to copy the original cells. Once the new generation has been computed, you must copy it back to the original `grid`: assuming `copyGrid` has the same geometry as `grid`, an array of `r` pointers to arrays of `c` ints, you must use a loop to copy this indirect 2D array.

Another approach is to use 2 global arrays and swap the pointers after computing each new generation.

Here is a modified version:

```
int **copyGrid;  // assuming this pointer points to an allocated grid

void updateGrid(int **grid, int r, int c) {
    // compute the new grid value in copyGrid
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            int alive = getState(grid, i, j); 
            int neighbours = countN(grid, i, j);
            if (alive) {
                if (neighbours < 2 || neighbours > 3) 
                    copyGrid[i][j] = 0;
                else 
                    copyGrid[i][j] = 1;
            } else {
                if (neighbour == 3) 
                    copyGrid[i][j] = 1;
                else 
                    copyGrid[i][j] = 0; 
            }
        }
    }
    // copy the new grid value from copyGrid back to grid
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = copyGrid[i][j];
        }
    }
    printGrid(grid, r, c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write `copyGrid = grid` your copy will point to the same memory location so you dont actually have a copy. You have to use

```
for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
memcpy(copyGrid[i],grid[i],sizeof(int)*c)
```

The reason for this is that you work with pointers.

Comment: Where does this do anything else than just copy the adress which grid holds to copyGrid?

Comment: Ok got that. I dont know why OP would do it that way but just to be correct i updated my answer.